# Separate values with commas on one line from a variable BASH

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a `bash` script which stores some values in a variable and outputs each value on a separate line like this:

```
2288
87
183
30
16
```

I need the values to be in this format on one line so I can export to `CSV`:

```
2288, 87, 183, 30, 16
```

I have looked at some examples online of using `sed` or `awk` but couldn't find an example similar to mine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste` is your friend:

```
$ paste -s -d',' file
2288,87,183,30,16
```

You can also use `tr` or `awk`, but you will get a trailing comma:

```
$ awk '{printf $0","}' file
2288,87,183,30,16,

$ tr -s '\n' ',' <file
2288,87,183,30,16,
```

---

### Update

> Its not a file its a variable I have it doesn't appear to work in the
>   same way?

Kind of:

```
$ myvar="2288
87
183
30"
$ echo "$myvar" | paste -s -d','
2288,87,183,30
$ echo "$myvar" | tr -s '\n' ', ' 
2288,87,183,30,
$ echo "$myvar" | awk '{printf $0","}'
2288,87,183,30,
```

Comment: Its not a file its a variable I have it doesn't appear to work in the same way?

Comment: The question wanted spaces after the commas.  You could also use `echo $myvar | tr ' ' ','` to get the result without spaces (no quotes around the variable so that internal newlines are converted to spaces by the shell).  Or, with spaces and commas, `echo $myvar | sed 's/ /, /g'`.  This also avoids trouble if the variable contains blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a bash array.  Place each value into the array (I'm using a longhand version):

```
declare -ai nums
nums+=(2288)
nums+=(87)
nums+=(183)
nums+=(30)
nums+=(16)

oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=','
echo "${nums[*]}"
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

The `declare -ai` declares `nums` as an array of integers.  Then we successively append each value to the array (these could be variables).  Setting `IFS` to a comma alters the default output separator.  It also changes the default input separator as well, so it is wise to store the old value of `IFS` then restore it when you are done (`oldIFS`).

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution.

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' RS= OFS=,
2288,87,183,30,16
```

This does not give the final `,` that many of the solution posted here has.

Answer (score 0):

sed solution:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' file
```

more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)